# Select specific hour and minute from getdate() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hour, getdate, minute

```
((DATEPART(HOUR, getdate()) BETWEEN 9 AND 15) or (DATEPART(HOUR, getdate())= 15 and (DATEPART(MINUTE, getdate()) between 00 and 30)))
```

The above is the query using for fetching data between 9AM to 03:30PM and Except 1PM.

But I need to modify this query to fetch data between 09:30 AM to 03:30 PM and except 1PM.

Can any one help me out here?

Comment: No - you did not accurately describe what your current query does - which means you might be misleading yourself and others. Your current query retrieves values between 9:00:00 and 15:59:59 - the OR part is irrelevant since the first part overlaps it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting to a `time` seems the easiest solution here.

```
WHERE CONVERT(time,GETDATE()) >= '09:30:00' AND CONVERT(time,GETDATE())< '15:30:00'
  AND NOT(CONVERT(time,GETDATE())>= '13:00:00' AND CONVERT(time,GETDATE())< '14:00:00')
```

Or you could do:

```
WHERE ((CONVERT(time,GETDATE())>= '09:30:00' AND CONVERT(time,GETDATE())< '13:00:00')
   OR  (CONVERT(time,GETDATE())>= '14:00:00' AND CONVERT(time,GETDATE())< '15:30:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

With Reference to your query.

```
((DATEPART(HOUR, getdate()) BETWEEN 10 AND 14)
AND (DATEPART(HOUR, getdate()) <> 13)
or (DATEPART(HOUR, getdate())= 15 and (DATEPART(MINUTE, getdate()) between 00 and 30))
OR (DATEPART(HOUR, getdate())= 9 and (DATEPART(MINUTE, getdate())  between 30 and 59)))
```

Comment: Actually, this will just return data between the hours of 09:00 and 15:59:59.9999999 As `DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 9 AND 15)` will be true for all those times.

Comment: @Larnu Can see once. I hope we answered.

Answer (score 0):

something similar to your implementation.

- first condition for between 10 AM to 3 PM
- second condition for between 3.00 PM to 3.30 PM
- third condition for between 9.30 AM to 9.59 AM

example:

```
((DATEPART(HOUR, getdate()) BETWEEN 10 AND 15) 
or (DATEPART(HOUR, getdate())= 15 and (DATEPART(MINUTE, getdate()) between 00 and 30))
or (DATEPART(HOUR, getdate())= 9 and (DATEPART(MINUTE, getdate()) between 30 and 59)))
```

NOTE: Exception case is not included.

Answer (score 0):

```
where cast(cast(getDate() as float) - floor(cast(getDate() as float)) as datetime)
    between '09:30:00' and '15:30:00'
    and datepart(hour, getDate())<>13
```

or

```
where convert(time, getDate())
    between '09:30:00' and '15:30:00'
    and datepart(hour, getDate())<>13
```

Comment: This seems like a really long winded way to convert `GETDATE()` to the same time on `1900-01-01` so that using a literal string for the time will work, when there is a `time` datatype in SQL Server.

Comment: I'm still working on some environment with SQL Server 2000 -no `time` datatype-.

Comment: 2000 has been long out of support @Xabi (over 6 years). Generally, you can assume that the OP is using a supported version of the product that they are asking about on Stack Overflow; as they will normally advise when using very old software. For SQL Server that's 2008-2017 (and 2008 only has a couple of monnhs left). Personally, if you are still using 2000, I would suggest looking to fix that problem soon, as it'll become a lot harder after 2008's support ends (as that is the latest version SQL Server 2000 can be restored on).

Answer (score 0):

`select * from test12 where (DATEPART(HOUR,Trackdatetime) >= 09 and DATEPART(MINUTE,Trackdatetime) >=30) 
and (DATEPART(HOUR,Trackdatetime) <= 15 and DATEPART(MINUTE,Trackdatetime) >=30) 
except
select * from test12 where (DATEPART(HOUR,Trackdatetime) = 13 and DATEPART(MINUTE,Trackdatetime) = 00)`